# Is there a way to determine whether a Windows Store app is suspended?

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps

I'm building a Windows Store app and it pops up toast notifications from time to time.  I also have an animation that plays to show when something has updated.  Both of these happen at the same time.

What I would like is to not show the toast when the app is running.

So, is there a nice easy way to determine this or do I have to manually track the state via the suspending/resuming events?

Edited info:
The solution has a background task project which goes off, gets the data, then decides if anything has changed that the user needs to know about.

If so, it creates a toast, updates the tile badge, and plays an animation to fade in the new data.

The issue is that I don't want to show the toast and update the tile badge if the user has the app full screen.  Similarly, playing the animation isn't needed until the app is resumed (that's the easy part though).

I realize I could solve it by having one timer that works when the app is running, and a separate background task for when it's suspended but that seems like overkill in this case.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer here is that if your app is suspended, your code won't be running.

If you want to pop up toasts when your app is suspended, you'll either need to use the WPNS or a background task to track changes.

Comment: WPNS I assume references the [Windows Notification Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh913756.aspx)?

Comment: also note that if using the WPNS = Windows Push Notification Service then while app is running you can 'eat the toast' by leveraging the [PushNotificationReceivedEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.pushnotifications.pushnotificationchannel.pushnotificationreceived.aspx) (kind of the inverse of the question originally asked)

Comment: @ZombieSheep Sorry, I wasn't clear with my question.  I've updated it with more information.